How to send only failed messages to DLQ in a Kafka batch listener with DefaultErrorHandler and DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer?
I have a batch listener:
@KafkaListener(
        id = "${spring.kafka.listener.cancel-auth-linkage.id}",
        topics = "${spring.kafka.listener.cancel-auth-linkage.topic.linkage}",
        autoStartup = "false",
        batch = "true",
        groupId = "cushion")
public void listen(List<Message<CancelAuthorizationLinkageResource>> messages) {
    ...
}

I need to handle ConversionException. If a ConversionException occurs, I want to send it to the Dead Letter Queue (DLQ). Therefore, I defined a DefaultErrorHandler and a DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.
   @Bean
    public DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer recoverer(KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> kafkaTemplate,
                                                   ListenerPropertiesServiceInterface listenerPropertiesServiceInterface) {
        return new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaTemplate,
                (r, e) -> {
                    if (e.getCause() instanceof ConversionException) {
                        if (r.key().equals(Objects.requireNonNull(((ConversionException) e.getCause()).getRecord())
                                .key())) {
                            return new TopicPartition(listenerPropertiesServiceInterface.getDlqTopic(), -1);
                        } else {
                            // Even though the non-failing messages are sent back to the original topic, they are not being consumed by the listener again.
                            return new TopicPartition(r.topic(), -1);
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                });
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer recoverer) {
        return new DefaultErrorHandler(recoverer);
    }

However, I noticed that if I fetch 10 messages at a time, and even if only one of them causes a ConversionException, my DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer processes all the messages (retrying the complete batch?). I want only the messages that caused the error to be sent to the DLQ or handled by the error handler. The messages without errors should still be processed normally by the listener.
How can I achieve this?
Edited:
@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CancelAuthorizationLinkageListener {
    private final CancelAuthorizationLinkageProcessor processor;
    private final ConcurrentMessageProcessor<CancelAuthorizationLinkageResource> messageProcessor;
    private final MessageRetryHandler messageRetryHandler;
    private final ListenerPropertiesServiceInterface listenerProperties;
    private final KafkaTemplate<String, CancelAuthorizationLinkageResource> kafkaTemplate;
    private final CushionKafkaMessageFactory cushionKafkaMessageFactory;

    @KafkaListener(
            id = "${spring.kafka.listener.cancel-auth-linkage.id}",
            topics = "${spring.kafka.listener.cancel-auth-linkage.topic.linkage}",
            autoStartup = "false",
            batch = "true",
            groupId = "cushion")
    public void listen(List<Message<CancelAuthorizationLinkageResource>> messages,
                       @Header(KafkaHeaders.CONVERSION_FAILURES) List<ConversionException> conversionExceptions) {
        log.debug("listener tx commit.");
    }
}

ERROR:
2024-08-05 23:57:25.845 ERROR 18496 --- [           main] [ ] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: A parameter of type 'List<Message<?>>' must be the only parameter (except for an optional 'Acknowledgment' and/or 'Consumer' and/or '@Header(KafkaHeaders.GROUP_ID) String groupId'
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97) ~[spring-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.determineInferredType(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:659) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.<init>(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:147) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.<init>(BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:88) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.createMessageListenerInstance(MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:210) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.createMessageListener(MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:176) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.setupMessageListener(AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:527) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.setupListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerEndpoint.java:510) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.createListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java:363) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.createListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java:66) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.createListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:287) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:195) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.registerAllEndpoints(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.java:196) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.java:186) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at jp.co.paypaycard.authorization.AuthorizationApplication.main(AuthorizationApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]


I think that is expected behavior and it is explained in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/annotation-error-handling.html#retrying-batch-eh. This is now the fallback behavior of the DefaultErrorHandler for a batch listener where the listener throws an exception other than a BatchListenerFailedException.

@ArtemBilan Yes, but do you know how I can ensure that the non-failing messages are sent back to the listener for processing?

That what BatchListenerFailedException with respective index is for. You cannot just drop a record in the middle of batch. That does not work with log-based messaging systems like Apache Kafka.

But if I use a batch listener that accepts List, I can’t get a List…

I don't think with your use-case you should look into that DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer at all. Sounds more like you are with something what is not going to work out of the box. So, handle that batch and its List<ConversionException> yourself in that listen() method.

@ArtemBilan Thank you very much! I agree with your point, but I am using a batch listener that receives List<Message>, so I cannot directly get a List. Could you please tell me how to obtain a List?

Why is that? I still think that @Header(KafkaHeaders.CONVERSION_FAILURES) List<ConversionException> conversionFailures is possible even if you use that List<Message<?>> for payload in your @KafkaListener.

@ArtemBilan I have updated my question and included my code along with the error message. If you have time, could you please take a look at it?

Yeah... I see. Indeed this one is not allowed together with the List<Message<?>>. I don't see a reason "why" since the item is going to be null in that list and no way to know what is going on. Feel free to raise a GH issue and we will look how to make this @Header(KafkaHeaders.CONVERSION_FAILURES) available as well. Meanwhile take a look into a workaround where you use List<CancelAuthorizationLinkageResource> payloads instead. The rest of required headers can be used like @Headers or via named one with a @Header.

@ArtemBilan I have found a temporary solution. I use the ErrorHandlingDeserializer to capture the exception and create an object with all member variables set to null via the failedDeserializationFunction. This way, I can replace the ConversionException. It is not very elegant, but it seems to work.
